# rosserial [ERROR] lost sync with device, restarting

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am building a differential drive robot using [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) package and [rosserial_tivac](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_tivac) to interface with my hardware I have written my codes and iclude them all in one launch file
when i use roslaunch every thing is working fine and the following message appear in terminal

```
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11918]
started core service [/rosout]
process[serial_gate_node-2]: started with pid [11935]
process[lpid_velocity-3]: started with pid [11936]
process[rpid_velocity-4]: started with pid [11937]
process[twist_to_motors-5]: started with pid [11938]
[INFO] [1534898274.948213]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1534898274.952975]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [1534898274.997246]: /twist_to_motors started
[INFO] [1534898277.081039]: Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes
[INFO] [1534898277.081769]: Setup publisher on lwheel [std_msgs/Int16]
[INFO] [1534898277.093732]: Setup publisher on rwheel [std_msgs/Int16]
[INFO] [1534898277.111318]: Note: subscribe buffer size is 512 bytes
[INFO] [1534898277.112105]: Setup subscriber on lmotor_cmd [std_msgs/Float32]
[INFO] [1534898277.126081]: Setup subscriber on rmotor_cmd [std_msgs/Float32]
```

Then when I try to publish a msg to the topic /twist that supposes to drive the robot. The motors start operating in the right direction but with a full speed which possibly means they didn't get the proper PWM value
and I am getting the following info appearing on my terminal

```
[INFO] [1534898288.361617]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[ERROR] [1534898302.098102]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

the codes witch I am using is from this [repository](https://github.com/ShehabAldeen/tripleX) if any one can help please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301174/rosserial-%5Berror%5D-lost-sync-with-device,-restarting-.../) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the message "wrong checksum for topic id and msg" indicates the real problem. This usually occurs when your headers files checksum definition in ROS are different from the rosserial client versions. It should be solved by running the rosserial_client make_library command again in ROS and update it on rosserial client side. The "Lost sync with device, restarting..." occurs with me as well and I am still looking for an answer for that, although the communication works properly with this messages.

---

Originally posted by [Fabricio Almeida](https://answers.ros.org/users/37122/fabricio-almeida/) with karma: 16 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0